# Power Query login attempts to database

Tags: db2, odbc, powerquery

I try to reach database (db2 based) via MS Power query ODBC driver. Database has policy that after 3 wrong password attempts it blocks id and password needs to be reseted. However PQ blocks ID right after first attempt.

So my question is:
- does PQ try to send several login request in the background? 
- if so can I somehow avoid this behavior? (maybe connection string or odbc.query options?)

Comment: What operating-system runs your Db2 *server* (where the database lives)?  Z/os,  AS/400 i-series ,   linux/unix/windows ?

Comment: This is not about db2 server. This is always different pc to pc - Sometimes its fine, sometimes not.

Comment: Password authentication is never performed by Db2-server itself, but instead either by the operating-system or LDAP or kerberos - to which Db2-server is configured to delegate. So: to see what the Power-Query (or ODBC driver) is *actually* asking the Db2-server to do, you can use the Db2-server diagnostics, and/or delegated authentication service diagnostics.  That is the reason why you should give details. You can also use ODBC trace at the client side.

Comment: Unfortunately I am only user of this database, so I cannot see these details. I tried ODBC trace but there is no timestamp, so hard to read. What is interesting college does not have such problem. He can connect w/o any problems - with same odbc and PQ settings (and I am sure I enter correct password).

Comment: stackoverflow is not the right forum for you, in this case. If you lack required diagnostic access, and other users don't have this issue, then either you are entering an incorrect password, or the password has some special character that your workstation is handling differently for some configuration reason or your software-levels/config differs from others. Can you connect successfully from another workstation reliably where others have no issues?   This is not a programming matter. This issue  requires competent problem-determination diagnostics access to be done at your side.

Comment: You are right, this is probably not right place. However I cleared all permissions in data source settings and entered credentials to login window and it finally passed. So now I just wonder if this is PQ bug or I did something wrong. On the top, when using ODBC connector login window does not show up when password expired or is wrong - but this is different topic.  As hundreds of people will use file (query) it would be difficult for some of them. Anyways, thank you.